# AJAX JQuery Database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Im trying to create a Ajax jquery with a drop down menu but i cant get I right.
I want to echo out how many members the site got from the selected country.
When I use numbers instead of countries as Option values I get it to work, but not when I use countries as option values. Please help

Index.php

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showUser(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","getcountry.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Globalbandfinder</title>
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>

<body>
<div id="top"></div>
<div id="holder">

<div id="banner"></div>
<div id="homebutton"></div>

  </p>
</h3>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>

<div id="aboutbutton"></div>


<div id="headlinescontent">
<h3><u><font face="Chaparral Pro"> Join </a>users in the search worldwide</u>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><span class="confirmMessage"><font size="4">Country:</font></span></br><font color="#FFFFFF">
<form>
<select name="country" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
<option value="">Please select a Country</option>
<option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option> 
<option value="Albania">Albania</option> 
<option value="Algeria">Algeria</option> 
<option value="Andorra">Andorra</option> 
<option value="Angola">Angola</option> 
<option value="Antigua">Antigua</option> 
<option value="Argentina">Argentina</option> 
<option value="Armenia">Armenia</option> 
<option value="Australia">Australia</option> 
<option value="Austria">Austria</option> 
<option value="Azerbaijan">Azerbaijan</option> 
<option value="Bahamas">Bahamas</option> 
<option value="Bahrain">Bahrain</option> 
<option value="Bangladesh">Bangladesh</option> 
<option value="Barbados">Barbados</option> 
<option value="Belarus">Belarus</option> 
<option value="Belgium">Belgium</option> 
<option value="Belize">Belize</option> 
<option value="Benin">Benin</option> 
<option value="Bermuda">Bermuda</option> 
<option value="Bhutan">Bhutan</option> 
<option value="Bolivia">Bolivia</option> 
<option value="Bosnia and Herzegovina">Bosnia and Herzegovina</option> 
<option value="Botswana">Botswana</option> 
<option value="Brazil">Brazil</option> 
<option value="Brunei Darussalam">Brunei Darussalam</option> 
<option value="Bulgaria">Bulgaria</option> 
<option value="Burkina Faso">Burkina Faso</option> 
<option value="Burma">Burma</option> 
<option value="Burundi">Burundi</option> 
<option value="Cambodia">Cambodia</option> 
<option value="Cameroon">Cameroon</option> 
<option value="Canada">Canada</option> 
<option value="Central African Republic">Central African Republic</option> 
<option value="Chad">Chad</option> 
<option value="Chile">Chile</option> 
<option value="China">China</option> 
<option value="Colombia">Colombia</option> 
<option value="Comoros">Comoros</option> 
<option value="DRC Provinces & City">DRC Provinces & City</option> 
<option value="CONGOLESE Regions & Commune">CONGOLESE Regions & Commune</option> 
<option value="Costa Rica">Costa Rica</option> 
<option value="Cote Divoire">Cote D'ivoire</option> 
<option value="Croatia">Croatia</option> 
<option value="Cuba">Cuba</option> 
<option value="Cyprus">Cyprus</option> 
<option value="Czech Republic">Czech Republic</option> 
<option value="Denmark">Denmark</option> 
<option value="Djibouti">Djibouti</option> 
<option value="Dominica">Dominica</option> 
<option value="Dominican Republic">Dominican Republic</option> 
<option value="Ecuador">Ecuador</option> 
<option value="Egypt">Egypt</option> 
<option value="El Salvador">El Salvador</option> 
<option value="Equatorial Guinea">Equatorial Guinea</option> 
<option value="Eritrea">Eritrea</option> 
<option value="Estonia">Estonia</option> 
<option value="Ethiopia">Ethiopia</option> 
<option value="Fiji">Fiji</option> 
<option value="Finland">Finland</option> 
<option value="France">France</option> 
<option value="Gabon">Gabon</option> 
<option value="Gambia">Gambia</option> 
<option value="Georgia">Georgia</option> 
<option value="Germany">Germany</option> 
<option value="Ghana">Ghana</option> 
<option value="Greece">Greece</option> 
<option value="Greenland">Greenland</option> 
<option value="Grenada">Grenada</option> 
<option value="Guatemala">Guatemala</option> 
<option value="Guinea">Guinea</option> 
<option value="Guinea-bissau">Guinea-bissau</option> 
<option value="Guyana">Guyana</option> 
<option value="Haiti">Haiti</option> 
<option value="Honduras">Honduras</option> 
<option value="Hungary">Hungary</option> 
<option value="Iceland">Iceland</option> 
<option value="India">India</option> 
<option value="Indonesia">Indonesia</option> 
<option value="Iran">Iran</option> 
<option value="Iraq">Iraq</option> 
<option value="Ireland">Ireland</option> 
<option value="Israel">Israel</option> 
<option value="Italy">Italy</option> 
<option value="Jamaica">Jamaica</option> 
<option value="Japan">Japan</option> 
<option value="Jordan">Jordan</option> 
<option value="Kazakhstan">Kazakhstan</option> 
<option value="Kenya">Kenya</option> 
<option value="Korea North">Korea North</option> 
<option value="Korea South">Korea South</option> 
<option value="Kuwait">Kuwait</option> 
<option value="Kyrgyzstan">Kyrgyzstan</option> 
<option value="Laos">Laos</option> 
<option value="Latvia">Latvia</option> 
<option value="Lebanon">Lebanon</option> 
<option value="Lesotho">Lesotho</option> 
<option value="Liberia">Liberia</option> 
<option value="Libya">Libya</option> 
<option value="Liechtenstein">Liechtenstein</option> 
<option value="Lithuania">Lithuania</option> 
<option value="Luxembourg">Luxembourg</option> 
<option value="Macedonia">Macedonia</option> 
<option value="Malawi">Malawi</option> 
<option value="Malaysia">Malaysia</option> 
<option value="Maldives">Maldives</option> 
<option value="Mali">Mali</option> 
<option value="Mauritania">Mauritania</option> 
<option value="Mauritius">Mauritius</option> 
<option value="Mayotte">Mayotte</option> 
<option value="Mexico">Mexico</option> 
<option value="Moldova">Moldova</option> 
<option value="Mongolia">Mongolia</option> 
<option value="Morocco">Morocco</option> 
<option value="Mozambique">Mozambique</option> 
<option value="Namibia">Namibia</option> 
<option value="Nepal">Nepal</option> 
<option value="Netherlands">Netherlands</option> 
<option value="New Zealand">New Zealand</option> 
<option value="Nicaragua">Nicaragua</option> 
<option value="Niger">Niger</option> 
<option value="Nigeria">Nigeria</option> 
<option value="Norway">Norway</option> 
<option value="Oman">Oman</option> 
<option value="Pakistan">Pakistan</option> 
<option value="Panama">Panama</option> 
<option value="Papua New Guinea">Papua New Guinea</option> 
<option value="Paraguay">Paraguay</option> 
<option value="Peru">Peru</option> 
<option value="Philippines">Philippines</option> 
<option value="Poland">Poland</option> 
<option value="Portugal">Portugal</option> 
<option value="Qatar">Qatar</option> 
<option value="Romania">Romania</option> 
<option value="Russia">Russia</option> 
<option value="Rwanda">Rwanda</option> 
<option value="Samoa">Samoa</option> 
<option value="San Marino">San Marino</option> 
<option value="Saudi Arabia">Saudi Arabia</option> 
<option value="Senegal">Senegal</option> 
<option value="Serbia">Serbia</option> 
<option value="Seychelles">Seychelles</option> 
<option value="Slovakia">Slovakia</option> 
<option value="Slovenia">Slovenia</option> 
<option value="Solomon Islands">Solomon Islands</option> 
<option value="Somalia">Somalia</option> 
<option value="South Africa">South Africa</option> 
<option value="Spain">Spain</option> 
<option value="Sri Lanka">Sri Lanka</option> 
<option value="Sudan">Sudan</option> 
<option value="Suriname">Suriname</option> 
<option value="Swaziland">Swaziland</option> 
<option value="Sweden">Sweden</option> 
<option value="Switzerland">Switzerland</option> 
<option value="Syria">Syria</option> 
<option value="Taiwan">Taiwan</option> 
<option value="Tanzania">Tanzania</option> 
<option value="Thailand">Thailand</option> 
<option value="Togo">Togo</option> 
<option value="Trinidad and Tobago">Trinidad and Tobago</option> 
<option value="Tunisia">Tunisia</option> 
<option value="Turkey">Turkey</option> 
<option value="Turkmenistan">Turkmenistan</option> 
<option value="Uganda">Uganda</option> 
<option value="Ukraine">Ukraine</option> 
<option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option> 
<option value="USA">USA</option> 
<option value="Uruguay">Uruguay</option> 
<option value="Uzbekistan">Uzbekistan</option> 
<option value="Vanuatu">Vanuatu</option> 
<option value="Venezuela">Venezuela</option> 
<option value="Vietnam">Vietnam</option> 
<option value="Yemen">Yemen</option> 
<option value="Zambia">Zambia</option> 
<option value="Zimbabwe">Zimbabwe</option>
</select>
</form>
<br>
<div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here.</b></div>

<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

getcountry.php

```
<?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);

$con = mysqli_connect("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","xxxxxxxxxxxxx","xxxxxxxxxx");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }

mysqli_select_db($con,"globalbandfinder");
$sql="SELECT * FROM info WHERE country = '".$q."'";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['fname'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['lname'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: where is `jQuery` in your posted question?

Comment: try changing $sql="SELECT * FROM info WHERE country = '".$q."'"; to 
$sql="SELECT * FROM info WHERE country = '{$q}'";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your using `intval` of `$_GET['q']` which will always return `0` if you pass a string.

For eg:

In your case if you select option `Afghanistan` the intval of this value will return 0.So remove the `intval` function and directly pass the value to `$q`.

Answer (score 0):

You can change this:

```
$q = intval($_GET['q']);
```

to this:

```
$q = $_GET['q'];
```

If you [go here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) it says:

> intval — Get the integer value of a variable